# Views slideshow - 3 items per slide - how to center them?

Tags: theming, views

I've been trawling the web on and off for months searching for an answer to the following:

I'm using Views Slideshow to show a series of logos in rotation. I have set there to be 3 items per slide in the slideshow settings. What I would like is for the three logos to be centred - i.e. an equal amount of space to either side of the logos. At the moment, they float left and I cannot for the life of me find the right CSS to do this, or where to add it.

I would really appreciate it if someone from the community could take a glance at the logo slideshow at the following url:

http://eunic-global.aptalops.com/

Please note that's it's the **rotating logo carousel at the bottom of the page** I'm having trouble with, **not the slider under the main menu**.

Best wishes, 
A~

Comment: Technically this is not about Drupal, but about CSS. Consider asking this question over at http://ux.stackexchange.com. You might easier get an answer there.

Comment: Yes you're right, I meant to preface my question with that but forgot. Thanks for the link. I think I'll leave it here  for the moment though in case any other suggestions come through and also post over at ux.stackexchange.com. A~

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_eunic_members-block {
margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: Thanks a million for taking a look at it. Did you find that this CSS snippet worked for you? Someone has marked your answer down - I'm afraid it didn't work for me either.

Comment: It's worked for me in firebug. 
But the logo are different sizes and dimensions of the container should do the same in width

Comment: wow. thanks for your reply. Any chance you could share a sreenshot of this? I'd be really interested in seeing one - I can't even get it to work in firebug! Thanks

Comment: Actually, it seems to be working now - not perfectly, but your comment has definitely put me on the right track. I think you might be right though: the only way to have it work perfectly is to have each logo the same width. Thanks again.